# How to clear UITextFields in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I created multiple text fields programatically. Their input is being read and after the answer is checked a new question is being posed to the user. 
But I don't seem to be able to clear the text fields, the previous input is still there. 
I tried already to add `textfield.text = ""` but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I should somehow delete the textfield with the correct tag, but I don't know how to do that. Does anybody have a suggestion for this situation?

```
var a = 0
while a < aantalNoten {
    let myTekstveld = UITextField()
    if (view.viewWithTag(a+1) as? UITextField) != nil {
        myTekstveld.text = ""
        }
        else {
            myTekstveld.frame = CGRect(x: labelX, y: labelY + 100, width: labelWidth, height: labelHeight / 2)
            myTekstveld.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            myTekstveld.textAlignment = .center
            myTekstveld.placeholder = "?"
            myTekstveld.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
            myTekstveld.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
            myTekstveld.autocorrectionType = .no
            myTekstveld.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
            myTekstveld.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing
            myTekstveld.textColor = UIColor.init(displayP3Red: CGFloat(96.0/255.0), green: CGFloat(35.0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(123.0/255.0), alpha: 1)
            myTekstveld.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
            myTekstveld.tag = a + 1
            view.addSubview(myTekstveld)
        }
        a += 1
        labelX += labelWidth
    }
```

Comment: You should maintain the text fields you create in an array and just iterate over them and clear them when needed. You seem to clearing the text of the new text field you create just before checking, which hasn't even been added to the view yet. Clear the existing text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find the `textfield` with tag. Here `view` is the super most view. Loop through all the subviews and find your `textField`.

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
   //Get One By One with Tag
   if let txtField1 = self.view.viewWithTag(tagOfTextField) as? UITextField {
       txtField1.text = ""
   }
}
```

Or you can clear all the `textfields`

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
    //Get All Values
    if let textField = view as? UITextField {
        textField.text = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
let myTekstveld = UITextField()
```

That creates a new local variable `myTekstveld` that only exists in the current scope. (Usually the innermost set of curly braces that enclose the code.) You are creating a text field, adding it to your view hierarchy, and then promptly forgetting about it.

You probably have an instance variable `myTekstveld` as well, but you are not setting that. That instance variable likely contains a DIFFERENT text field.

Remove the word `let` from your code and it will save your newly created text field to your instance variable

Add a new line just above your `myTekstveld = UITextField()` line that says:

```
print("myTekstveld = \(myTekstveld)")
```

And see what it displays to the debug console.

If it logs a text field, you should probably get rid of the `myTekstveld = UITextField()` line entirely and just configure the existing text field rather than replacing the text field with a new one.

Answer (score -4):

Check this  :

```
  textfield.text = nil
```

Comment: Please provide details on how this code works, compared to the question? When you explain your answer in addition to the code, it will be helpful to all the readers.

Comment: it will work in an action, like when a button is pressed.

Comment: Rather than just guess at answers, it's worth trying them out in a playground first